# How to force cloudfront to use https (redirect http -> https)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I am hosting a static site on aws via s3/coludfront. Anyway I can force cloudfront to redirect all http request to https version.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To force http -> https.

1. Go to the cloudfront distribution
2. Select the distribution
3. Go to behaviour
4. select the one and click edit
5. Now you have a option of redirecting http -> https

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/46481196/5473824 for how this is done in cloudformation .

Answer (score 6):

If you're using CloudFormation:

```
Resources:
  Distribution:
    Type: AWS::CloudFront::Distribution
    Properties:
      ...
      DistributionConfig:
        DefaultCacheBehavior:
          ViewerProtocolPolicy: redirect-to-https
        ...
```

Previous answer said to use https-only but that will return a 403 (Forbidden) if the viewer sends an HTTP request.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/latest/APIReference/API_CacheBehavior.html